# get stuck to reifyNode:node_modules/@types/node when installing puppeteer with npm get any idea how to fix it?

Tags: node.js, npm, installation, puppeteer

Hello I am stuck with the installation of puppeteer with npm, I delete manually some node file in my computer like in lib to uninstall but I think it cause this problem. I tried to uninstall node and install again but it's not working..
Does anyone can help me please !! thank you for any help!!

Comment: What's the error message?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to downgrade npm to version 6. I experienced same issue sometimes and downgrading npm helped.